# Why DOMParser requires to be instantiated?

Tags: javascript

One of the preferred native methods to create DOM elements from a string a la `jQuery` is to use the new `DOMParser` class. This example is extracted from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(aStr, "text/xml");
```

I wonder if there is any particular reason to the extra-step that requires to instantiate a parser before parsing a string. I.e. why can't we just do something like `parseFromString(aStr, "text/xml");` ?

The parser object looks superfluous. [DOMParser constructor doesn't even have any arguments and its instances doesn't have any method other than `parseFromString`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Parsing/#the-domparser-interface).

Comment: Future-proofing, perhaps?

Comment: I am not sure but i believe untill instantiating DOMParser is just a function and takes less memory( or some other resourse ). So in case you never need it, it is not instantiated to not cause unneeded overhead

Comment: @guramidev, I agree. I believe this is likely to be the main reason for this, but I am surprised it requires *that much* resources so that you do not even want to automatically allocated them just when the `parseFromString` function is called.

Comment: Well, you could always do `function parseFromString(str, t) { return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, t); }`.

Comment: @melpomene, OK. But my question is why this isn't native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, putting up a DOM parser ready to parse text is an expensive operation (memory-wise), so in order to save the memory hit from setting up a DOM parser for each page/tab you visit, the browser will clear the memory from the initial DOM parser it instantiates (to parse the document's source), and unless you instantiate it again, that memory is clear.

If you want, you can use the profiler tool in your favorite browser to see how memory changes before and after instantiating the DOM parser.